# Force foundry to ignore contracts during a coverage report

Tags: foundry, coverage

Right now, in [foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry), if I run my coverage report, sometimes it'll include my mocks, which I don't want.

Example:

```
| File                                                       | % Lines         | % Statements     | % Branches     | % Funcs         |
|------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------|------------------|----------------|-----------------|
| src/protocol/MyCode.sol                           | 100.00% (1/1)   | 100.00% (1/1)    | 100.00% (0/0)  | 100.00% (1/1)   |
| src/mocks/MyMock.sol                          | 0.00% (0/3)     | 0.00% (0/4)      | 100.00% (0/0)  | 0.00% (0/3)     |
```

How would I ignore `MyMock.sol`?

Answer (score 0):

As of writing, there is an [active ticket](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/2988) to exclude contracts from the coverage report.

For the time being, here is a workaround for files that foundry just won’t ignore. Add this line to any file you’d like to exclude.

```js
    // add this to be excluded from coverage report
    function test() public {}
```

Forge will see the `test` prefix, assume the file is a test file, and ignore the file from the coverage report. If you have a file that inherits a file where you already added a test function, you can then do like:

```js
    // add this to be excluded from coverage report
    function testA() public {}
```